# For Loop And Array Issue - ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I have an array that contains some data called, well, `data`.

Data looks like:

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'Gray',
    choice_no: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'one',
    choice_no: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'two',
    choice_no: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'three',
    choice_no: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'four',
    choice_no: 2
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'five',
    choice_no: 2
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: 'title',
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 1.12,
    choice1: 'Color',
    choice2: 'Size',
    large_picture: 'picture',
    choice: 'Black',
    choice_no: 1
  },
];
```

I am currently trying to loop through `data` to separate them into two separate arrays: `color` and `size`.

Now `data`'s objects will not always have `choice1` or `choice2` as properties. ( Just a side note for later )

I am checking for the second choice and doing the loop as such:

```js
if (data[0].choice2) {
  // Has 2 choices
  for (var i in data) {

    if (data[i].choice1.toUpperCase() == 'SIZE' && data[i].choice_no == 1) {
      size[i] = {
        choice: data[i].choice,
        order: data[i].sort
      };
    } else if (data[i].choice2.toUpperCase() == 'SIZE' && data[i].choice_no == 2) {
      size[i] = {
        choice: data[i].choice,
        order: data[i].sort
      };
    } else if (data[i].choice1.toUpperCase() == 'COLOR' && data[i].choice_no == 1) {
      color[i] = {
        choice: data[i].choice,
        order: data[i].sort
      };
    } else if (data[i].choice2.toUpperCase() == 'COLOR' && data[i].choice_no == 2) {
      color[i] = {
        choice: data[i].choice,
        order: data[i].sort
      };
    }

  } // End for()

}
```

This **kind of** works. `color.length` = 7, though, when it should only equal 2. If I loop through it like:

```js
for ( var x in color ) {
  console.log(color[x]);  
}
```

It outputs:

```js
Object {choice: "Gray", order: 2}
Object {choice: "Black", order: 1}
```

But if I change the loop to `var x = 0; x < color.length; x++` it loops through 0-6 and everything between "Gray" and "Black" is `undefined`. Now I would just use the first loop as it 'works' but `ngRepeat` works similar to the second array. It loops through all 7 records.

### TL;DR

I'm pretty sure I messed up somewhere on my `if` block trying to separate `choice1` and `choice2` into their proper arrays ( color & size ).
It is **important** to note that `choice1` will **NOT** always be color ( `choice1` could be size ) and there may not even be ANY choices. Also I am very limited to how I can modify data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of setting the array with an index try using the method `.push()`

like so:

```
if (data[i].choice1.toUpperCase() == 'SIZE' && data[i].choice_no == 1) {
  size.push({ // <--- .push( instead of [i] = 
    choice: data[i].choice,
    order: data[i].sort
  });
} else ...
```

Comment: It actually took me longer to write the question than to get an answer. Thanks. Will accept in ~8min when it lets me!